# Replace Subscripts in FindRoot solution to a boundary-value problem

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, nonlinear, subscript

`FindRoot` has a nice example to solve a boundary-value problem for a second-order ordinary differential equation using "collocation points" to turn the ODE into a set of nonlinear coupled algebraic equations.  It seems to run much faster than NDSolve, so I'd like to use it.  I am having troubles that trace back to the use of subscripts, which are discouraged in any case.  I'd like to replace the subscripts by something equivalent (e.g. defining a 2 by n matrix of variables) but am having difficulties.

Here is the code (copied and slightly simplified from FindRoot / Applications/Solving boundary value problems, 2nd example).  Use n=100 for a prettier graph.

```
n = 10;
f[{u_, v_}] := {v, (1 - u - u^3)/0.01};
eqns = Flatten[Join[{Subscript[u, 0], Subscript[u, n]},
    Table[{Subscript[u, i], Subscript[v, i]} - {Subscript[u, i - 1], 
       Subscript[v, i - 1]} + 
      1/(2 n) (f[{Subscript[u, i - 1], Subscript[v, i - 1]}] + 
         f[{Subscript[u, i], Subscript[v, i]}]), {i, 1, n}]]];
sv = Flatten[
   Table[{{Subscript[u, i], 0}, {Subscript[v, i], 0}}, {i, 0, n}], 
   1];
froot = FindRoot[eqns, sv];
sol = Table[Subscript[u, i], {i, 0, n}] /. froot;
ListLinePlot[sol]
```

This runs and produces the plot in the `FindRoot` documentation.  The naive "solution" is to replace the subscripts with `Part` but it generates errors.  Suggestions will be appreciated!

```
eqns = Flatten[Join[{u[[0]], u[[n]]},
    Table[{u[[i]], v[[i]]} - {u[[i - 1]], v[[i - 1]]} + 
      1/(2 n) (f[{u[[i - 1]], v[[i - 1]]}] + f[{u[[i]], v[[i]]}]), {i,
       1, n}]]];
sv = Flatten[Table[{{u[[i]], 0}, {v[[i]], 0}}, {i, 0, n}], 1];
froot = FindRoot[eqns, sv];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Array` as follows

```
n = 100;
f[{u_, v_}] := {v, (1 - u - u^3)/0.01}; U = 
 Array[u, {n + 1}, {0, n}]; V = Array[v, {n + 1}, {0, n}];

eqns = Flatten[
   Join[{u[0], u[n]}, 
    Table[{u[i], v[i]} - {u[i - 1], v[i - 1]} + 
      1/(2 n) (f[{u[i - 1], v[i - 1]}] + f[{u[i], v[i]}]), {i, 1, 
      n}]]];
sv = Flatten[Table[{{u[i], 0}, {v[i], 0}}, {i, 0, n}], 1];
froot = FindRoot[eqns, sv];

{ListLinePlot[U /. froot], ListLinePlot[V /. froot]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I was looking for.